# Change string to be const

Tags: c#, .net, string

Someone told me to place my entire application strings in const instead of inline.

Why is that?

Does it improve compilation time? run time? or just code standard?

**example**

instead of writing:

```
selectSingleNode.InnerText == "SomeString"
```

write

```
selectSingleNode.InnerText == SOME_CONST
```

Comment: They are not `const` by default. You mean `immutable` instead?

Comment: This question is quite broad. Are you talking about string literals?

Comment: Strings the way I see it are always immutable. He told me I should write service.SomeStringManipulation(TEST_CONST);  instead of service.SomeStringManipulation("test");

Comment: Your friend is telling you to avoid [magic literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string).

Comment: He probably wants you to do that because it is more maintainable and less error-prune to use constants vs string literals. The performance gain will be neglectable.

Comment: As long as you're going to use same string literals in more than one place in your code, you should use constants. One of the obvious examples is the `database connection string`.

Comment: remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil. dont do this unless you use this string in multiple places. and do this just for readability not for performance or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You would do this purely for maintainability and readability.  Using a named constant instead of a string literal will have no performance impact whatsoever.

**Maintainability**

If you have multiple places in the code that require the same string literal, having them all use the same named constant makes your code a lot more maintainable.  If you ever decide you need to change the value of the string literal, there is only one place you need to make the change.

**Readability**

Even if your string literal is used in a single place, providing a named constant may make your code more readable.

For instance, in the following sample, which version do you feel conveys the intent more clearly?

```
// string literals
int startIdx = someString.IndexOf("[");
int endIdx = someString.IndexOf("]");

// vs. named constants
int startIdx = someString.IndexOf(TAG_START);
int endIdx = someString.IndexOf(TAG_END);
```

A properly chosen name for a constant can make the code's intent clearer.  But the key here is that you have to pick a good name.  Too often, I'll see things like:

```
private const string ASTERISK = "*"; // very poor name
```

That is a very poorly chosen constant name that doesn't help readability one bit. The problem is that it simply states the contents of the string literal, when instead, it should be communicating what the string literal is used for.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some tests where developers have tested execution time and IL generated between using const and non-const strings. It's true there is the slightest of performance gain from using const (though insignificant unless you're working for nasa or Wall Street) the real benefits are:

1. You are ensuring your values are immutable.
2. You are defining literals in one location instead of writing them inline. If you need to change a value in the future it should be easier.

This isn't exhaustive and I'm anxious to see what others post as well. Hope this at least helps.

Comment: He's comparing `const` to literals.  Variables, performance, and mutability are not issues.

Comment: Your response was helpful! thanks. I'm anxious as well!